# Python. Проблема со Scapy

Tags: python, arp, scapy

Вот код:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst=ip)
    print(arp_request.summary())

scan("192.168.1.1/24")
```

Вот что выводит:

> ARP who has ?? says ??

Вместо вопросов, должны быть ip адреса.
Прошу помощи.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259896

Answer (score 0):

Была такая-же проблема. Помогли вот эти команды:

```
pip uninstall scapy

pip install scapy==2.4.0

pip3 install scapy==2.4.0
```

Если нет `pip`, то:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```